# Gnuplot x tic labels overlap

Tags: charts, gnuplot

I am drawing a gnuplot chart from datafile with such format:

```
01 value_1_1 value_2_1
02 value_1_1 value_2_1
...
01 value_1_n value_2_n
```

using that command:

```
plot "action.dat" using 2:xtic(1) with boxes ls 1 title "First title",\
     "action.dat" using 3:xtic(1) with boxes ls 2 title "Second title";
```

X tic labels are loaded from the first column. When terminal is too small, labels start to overlap. How can I hide x tic label if it overlaps previous label? Or, at least, how can I draw only n-th label?

I've tried to do something like that

```
set xtics 10 rotate by -90
```

but failed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47351617/2707864

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To (effectively) plot every nth label, you can use something like:

```
plot "action.dat" using 2:xtic(int($0)%3==1 ? strcol(1):'') with boxes ls 1 title "First title"
```

This will actually plot *every* label, but the ones that aren't the n'th label will just be plotted as empty strings ...

Comment: Thanks. Your code is exactly I was looking for: xtic(int(strcol(1))%4==1 ? strcol(1):''). Not an automatic overlap detection, but it works perfect too.